# Custom Generic List for extending methods

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following class:

```
public class ListDemo<T> : IList<T>
{
    private List<T> list = new List<T>(); // Internal list
    public void Add(T item)
    {
       // Do your pre-add logic here
       list.Add(item); // add to the internal list
       // Do your post-add logic here
    }

    // Implement all IList<T> methods, just passing through to list, such as:
}
```

Then in my code I have:

```
AuditList<Entities.SetupCenterCode> _centerCodes = new AuditList<Entities.SetupCenterCode>();

using (Logistics.Data.ConfigurationWCF svc = new Data.ConfigurationWCF())
{
    _centerCodes = svc.GetCenterCodes(_entity);

    foreach (var item in _centerCodes)
    {
        item.StartTracking();
    }
}
```

But I get an error here with the conversion because `svc.GetCenterCodes(_entity);` returns a traditional `List<>`

[image]

How can I solve this, is strange because my custom `ListDemo` class is for built for generic list.

> Any clue?

Comment: Why not create a constructor for your custom list that can take a `List<T>`?

Comment: mm the constructor should be good idea, any clue on how the constructor should be?

Comment: Why are you creating your own list in the first place?  Just use a `List<T>`.

Comment: The screenshot you're showing doesn't look like the code you've shown in the question. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Servy because I need to know if an item in the list is new or not, by setting a custom property.

Comment: Then you can use ObservableColletion, no?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a private constructor that takes a list and then use the implicit operator to cast directly from list:

```
public class MyList<T>
{
    private List<T> myList;

    private MyList(List<T> myList)
    {
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyList<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        return new MyList<T>(list);
    }
}
```

Then, Your rest of the code will work without a change:

```
List<SomeObject> list = new List<SomeObject>();
MyList<SomeObject> myList = list;
```